# How to use Python ast module's NodeTransformer class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying switch all ">=" in my program to "<". This is what I have so far:

```
import ast
from astor import to_source

class Visitor(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def generic_visit(self, node):
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_GtE(self, node):
        node2 = ast.Lt()
        ast.copy_location(node2, node)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node2)
        return node2

def mutate(filename, numMutations):
    file = open(filename)
    contents = file.read()
    parsed = ast.parse(contents)
    nodeVisitor = Visitor()
    nodeVisitor.visit(parsed)
    print(to_source(parsed))
```

When I call mutate, nothing get's changed. What's wrong with my visit_GtE method?

Answer (score 3):

The `NodeTransformer` does not transform an AST in-place.  The `visit` method returns a *new* AST.  So you need to assign this to a variable in your mutate function, and output the new AST.

```
def mutate(filename, numMutations):
    file = open(filename)
    contents = file.read()
    parsed = ast.parse(contents)
    nodeVisitor = Visitor()
    # Capture the new AST.
    transformed = nodeVisitor.visit(parsed)
    print(to_source(transformed))
```